# How to determine what caused WebGrid to trigger ajaxUpdateCallback

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, webgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

Got a page that is mostly working to display a WebGrid (MVC 5) and a Bootstrap 3.0.2 modal for editing rows (jQuery 2.0.3). Just one little problem... the dialog appears not only when I click on a row but *also* when I click on the sort links in the column headers and the pager links. Ideally, I'd like to just be able to differentiate what triggered the ajaxUpdateCallback so that I can conditionally display the modal in my callback handler.

Here's code from my view...

```
@using School.Models
@model IEnumerable<Course>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Courses";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 15, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent", ajaxUpdateCallback: "webGridUpdated");
}
<div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid", @class = "table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" },
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Name", header: string.Format("Name {0}", grid.SortColumn == "Name" ? grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "▼" : "▲" : ""),
                format: @<text>@item.GetSelectLink(item.Name)</text>),
            grid.Column("Active", header: string.Format("Active {0}", grid.SortColumn == "Active" ? grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "▼" : "▲" : ""),
                format: (item) =>
                {
                    var course = item.Value as Course;
                    return Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => course.Active);
                }
            )
        )
    )

    @if (grid.HasSelection)
    {
        @Html.Partial("Edit", (Course)grid.SelectedRow.Value)
    }
    else // New Course
    {
        @Html.Partial("Create", new Course() { })
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function webGridUpdated() {
        // Would like to be able to wrap this in a conditional
        $('#EditModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome dev tools, you can set a breakpoint on "Any XHR" event. Once the breakpoint is hit, you might be able to look at the call stack to determine what triggered the XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the form action for my modal dialog was being set using AJAX to /Courses/Edit/4 (or any non-zero integer) if I click on a row in the grid but /Courses/Edit/0 if I clicked on the Sort or Pager hyperlinks. So I added some code to my grid's callback to check this and conditionally open the Bootstrap modal.